# LightSwitch HTML application for Mobile Application

Tags: c#, android, jquery, cordova, visual-studio-lightswitch

Can we use LightSwitch Html application for developing mobile applications.

I know, we can build mobile application for various platform like Android, iPhone...with HTML5 , Jquery and Phonegap.

So Is there any way to use [Microsoft Html LightSwitch application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj674624.aspx) for building mobile application like we develop using phonegap?

Comment: `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn296545.aspx` said ios and android were supported

Answer (score 0):

In our experience, the LightSwitch HTML client can be used to successfully develop professional applications that support both of these mobile platforms.

The reason for this is that, the LightSwitch HTML client utilises the [jQuery Mobile](https://jquerymobile.com/) HTML5 based framework which includes Android and iOS as part of its cross platform audience.